# Фильтрация json

Tags: json, yandex-metrika-api

Салют. Вывожу статистику на сайте, используя api метрики. 
Получаю json:

```
{
  "data" : [{
    "page_views" : 42372,
    "exit" : 4936,
    "url" : "http://site.ru/1",
    "id" : "8618571366154354830",
    "entrance" : 23313
  },
  {
    "page_views" : 5733,
    "exit" : 3447,
    "url" : "http://site.ru/2",
    "id" : "2337054517222985888",
    "entrance" : 1462
  }]
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно получить значение page_views, url которого http://site.ru/2

Answer (score 3):

```
var t = {
    "data": [{
        "page_views": 42372,
        "exit": 4936,
        "url": "http://site.ru/1",
        "id": "8618571366154354830",
        "entrance": 23313
    }, {
        "page_views": 5733,
        "exit": 3447,
        "url": "http://site.ru/2",
        "id": "2337054517222985888",
        "entrance": 1462
    }]
};

var required_site;
for (var i = t.data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var e = t.data[i];
    if (e.url == 'http://site.ru/2') {
        required_site = e;
        break;
    };
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но как это на php реализовать?

Comment: Так же — в цикле бегите по массиву `data` и сравнивайте свойство `url` c  необходимой вам константой.

И в будущем сразу указывайте с чем конкретно у вас проблема, что не получается, листинг вашего кода.